# Pitest mutation testing execute over kotlin files only

Tags: java, kotlin, mutation-testing, pitest

I arrived to a legacy project where multiple files are developed in **Java** and many others in **Kotlin**. I have be able to configure **Pitest** to execute the mutation test and i have a correct report.

Now I would like to execute the mutation test only over the Kotlin files.

I tried to use the `<targetClasses>` but the param expresion is able to include certain packages, but I didn't discover a way to include certain types of files only.

I also tried to use the `<excludedClasses>` to add there a Java identificator that exclude this type of files, but again it doesn't work.

Do you know a way to use the targetClasses or the excludedClasses to let the kotlin files only in the scope of the Pitest execution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way to limit mutation to only kotlin files. You would need to implement an mutation interceptor.

https://pitest.org/quickstart/advanced/

Or use the exclusions functionality provided by the arcmutate extentions to ignore files with a .java extension.

https://docs.arcmutate.com/docs/exclusions.html